# Reading line by line from a file in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I am a newbie in Unix I have a file which contains a list of file names. I am trying to copy every file in the same directory but with a different extension. Its not working. Can anyone tell me why my code is bellow csl_nl.sts is the file with name of other files?

```
#!/bin/csh
set files = ("csl_nl.sts")
foreach file ('cat files')

  echo "Copying" $file "to" $file.cdc
  cp $file $file.cdc

end
exit 0
```

Comment: I can't understand your question. What's your expected and actual output?

Comment: Its not working i am not getting any out put my expected output is to create copies of file in the list in the same directory in which they exist

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me

```
#!/bin/csh

foreach file (`cat csl_nl.sts`)
    set a=`echo $file | awk -F"." '{print $1}'`
    echo "$a"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/ksh

OLD_EXTN=old
NEW_EXTN=new

cat csl_nl.sts | while read line;
do
  if [ ! -f $line];
  then
    echo $line does not exist ;
  else
    newfn=$(dirname $line)/$(basename $line .$OLD_EXTN).$NEW_EXTN
    echo Copy from $line to $newfn
    cp $line $newfn;
  fi
done
```

Comment: @AyaAbdelsalam "No such file or directory". One of the files in your list doesn't exist or has spaces in the name.

Answer (score -1):

see if this helps:

```
#!/bin/csh
  set files = ("abc")
  foreach file (`cat $files`)
    set ext = ("cdc")
    set file2 = "$file.$ext"
    echo "Copying" $file "to" $file2;
    cp $file $file2;

  end
exit 0
```

Comment: I would appreciate if the person who downvoted this answer also gives the reason.

Answer (score -2):

Can't say I'm familiar with (t)csh, but, here's the obligatory bash example:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in `cat csl_ns.tst`; do
echo $file  " -> "  $file.cdc
cp $file $file.cdc
done
```

Depends on the formatting of the input file, but that should work if they're seperated by whitespace or lines.

Comment: In this case, given that I don't know the format of this file, I want the behavior that skips blank lines and splits spaced lines. That being said, I did not know about the other pitfalls, and that proved to be some very interesting information.