# separation of 2 parameters by using cut command

Tags: unix, scripting, set, cut, tcsh

I have a file with 2 columns. For each line I need insert both parameters to variables: `var1` should get the first value and `var2` the second one

Input file for example:

```
  38452 d0337358
  38453 d0337357
  38454 d0337363
```

And I do it with `set` and `cut`:

```
foreach f (cat file)
foreach? set var1 = ( echo $f | cut -f1 -d- )
foreach? set var2 = ( echo $f | cut -f2 -d- )
foreach? echo $var1
foreach? end
```

But as output I get:

```
38452
d0337358
38453
d0337357
38454
d0337363
```

And not just parameters of the first column.

Can anybody point the problems in the `foreach` body? Or does anybody know a better way to do that?

Comment: tried also few combination as :

set var1 = `( echo $f | cut -d ' ' -f 1 )`

Comment: it is not clear what you mean. Try to specify clearly what is the input, what is the output and what is the expected output

Comment: first example is for input file.
i give to the var1 the first value and print it but as output i get both values.

i need that var1 will get the first value and var2 the second one

Comment: No, update your question with these informations. You may want to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading line by line from a file in unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306289/reading-line-by-line-from-a-file-in-unix)

Comment: no, it's a little bit different. I need the both values from the input file and i don't success to get them

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop through a file and read every column separatedly, you can use a `while` loop like this:

```
while IFS=" " read -r var1 var2
do
   echo "var1=$var1, var2=$var2"
done < file
```

Note that you were using `foreach`, which does not exist in Bash. Also, there is no need to `set` variables: just saying `var="value"` sets them.

#### Explanation

- `IFS=" "` sets the field separator to the space.
- ' read -r var1 var2`sets the first word to the variable`$var1`and the rest to the variable`$var2`.
- `while; do ... done < file` is a good way to process a file, by giving its content through the indirection `<`.

#### Test

```
$ while IFS=" " read -r var1 var2; do echo "var1=$var1, var2=$var2"; done < a
var1=38452, var2=d0337358
var1=38453, var2=d0337357
var1=38454, var2=d0337363
```

Comment: You can even remove it: `while read -r var1 var2`. Does it work to you?

Comment: No,
it suggests:
while `read -r var1 var2`
read: Command not found.
CORRECT>while `mread -r var1 var2` (y|n|e|a)?

Comment: It doesn't help, there the second value is constant.

Comment: Then maybe http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/csh-while-read-738708/

Comment: May I know the reason for a +1 and -1 on the same day, without comments and almost two months later? :O

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the way "cat file" reads the contents of file. It uses spaces as delimiter, not the end of line.

So a simple solution, assuming the input file will always have 2 columns:

```
set n = 1
foreach f ( `cat file` )
    if ( $n % 2 == 1 ) then
        set var1 = $f
    else
        set var2 = $f
        echo $var1
    endif
    @ n++
end
```